# How to disable/enable a VisualState based on some condition? (Metro)

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, visualstatemanager

I defined a VisualState for a button in a controltemplate:

```xml
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
      ...
      <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
          ...
          <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
            <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="c1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.7"/>
            </Storyboard>
          </VisualState>
          ...
        </VisualStateGroup>
      </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      ...
  </ControlTemplate>
```

But this effect (change opacity when mouseover) should be enabled/disabled based on a viewmodel condition, so how do I do that with XAML?

I tried creating a binding for the To value of the DoubleAnimation, it doesn't work because Storyboard is freezed. I'm also thinking sth like a template selector, but there is no such thing for the VisualState Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was discussing it recently with someone and I might add a generic solution to the problem to the WinRT XAML Toolkit, which would work similar to DataTriggers from WPF, but for now I would just add a `DependencyProperty` to your control, bind the property to your view model and on value change - update the visual state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when you say "update the visual state", do you mean "switch to another visual state" or "change the logical tree of the VisualStateManager". For the former, it doesn't work because the "PointerOver" state can be triggered by the mouse action, so even if I manually switch to another state, the "PointerOver" state is still alive, it will still be triggered when the mouse is over unless I can "disable" it. For the latter, I need to first find the VisualState object in C#, but it seems it's not in the visual tree. (can't find it with GetDescendants() on the Button)

Comment: I did mean "switch to another visual state". If `PointerOver` gets overriden by the Button's logic - clear up its `Storyboard`s and add your own custom `CustomPointerOver` state in a new `VisualStateGroup` that does what you want that the button knows nothing about so it won't use or override it. I don't think you need to modify the setup of your `VisualStateGroup`s at runtime, but GetDescendants() only works for visual tree elements (`UIElement`s) and `VisualStateManager` isn't one.

Comment: Thanks. It worked! Never thought about I can use mixed states (both Button knows and doesn't know) in the same VisualStateGroup. I just need to handle the PointerEntered event and based on the condition to decide wether or not to go to my CustomPointerOver state.